# Как в spring обработать body в виде json?

Tags: java, json, spring, post, spring-mvc

Пытаюсь изучить api в spring. GET Запрос хорошо посылается, а вот POST пока сложно

```java
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/pay",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public @ResponseBody void pay(String key) {
    System.out.println();
}
```

Не знаю куда отправляется json, и как дальше работать с ним в рамках спринга. Заранее спасибо за разъяснения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно возвращать [`ResponseEntity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) и передавать в него какой-либо объект, а `Spring` сделает из него `json`. Например, можно передать карту:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/pay", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> pay(String key) {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key", key);
    map.put("OK", 200);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(map);
}
```

Для этого нужно подключить библиотеку `jackson-databind`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.3</version>
</dependency>
```