# Spring. Как отправить 401 код и другие?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, response

Есть RequestMapping:

```java
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/login",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public UUID restMethod(String hashCredentials) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println(hashCredentials + " | ");
    UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
    //dbHandler.getAllUsers();
    return id;
}
```

Он отвечает всегда 200. Вопрос в том, как поменять responseCode и добавить нужную информацию в body в виде json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно возвращать [`ResponseEntity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html), а в него заворачивать объект:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/login", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<UUID> restMethod(String hashCredentials) {
    System.out.println(hashCredentials + " | ");
    UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
    //dbHandler.getAllUsers();
    return ResponseEntity.status(401).body(id);
}
```

---

См. [Как в spring обработать body в виде json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1200214/236980)